# Using PostgreSQL JSON function to obtain an array object from a JSON stored key

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table on AWS RDS PostgreSQL that stores JSON objects. For instance I have this registry:

```
{
  "id": "87b05c62-4153-4341-9b58-e86bade25ffd",
  "title": "Just Ok",
  "rating": 2,
  "gallery": [
    {
      "id": "1cb158af-0983-4bac-9e4f-0274b3836cdd",
      "typeCode": "PHOTO"
    },
    {
      "id": "aae64f19-22a8-4da7-b40a-fbbd8b2ef30b",
      "typeCode": "PHOTO"
    }
  ],
  "reviewer": {
    "memberId": "2acf2ea7-7a37-42d8-a019-3d9467cbdcd1",
  },
  "timestamp": {
    "createdAt": "2011-03-30T09:52:36.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2011-03-30T09:52:36.000Z"
  },
  "isUserVerified": true,
}
```

And I would like to create a query for obtaining one of the `gallery` objects.
I have tried this but get both objects in the array:

```
SELECT jsonb_path_query(data->'gallery', '$[*]') AS content
FROM public.reviews
WHERE jsonb_path_query_first(data->'gallery', '$.id') ? '1cb158af-0983-4bac-9e4f-0274b3836cdd'
```

With this other query I get the first object:

```
SELECT jsonb_path_query_first(data->'gallery', '$[*]') AS content
FROM public.reviews
WHERE jsonb_path_query_first(data->'gallery', '$.id') ? '1cb158af-0983-4bac-9e4f-0274b3836cdd'
```

But filtering by the second array object id, I get no result:

```
SELECT jsonb_path_query_first(data->'gallery', '$[*]') AS content
FROM public.reviews
WHERE jsonb_path_query_first(data->'gallery', '$.id') ? 'aae64f19-22a8-4da7-b40a-fbbd8b2ef30b'
```

I have read the [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) and tried other functions like `jsonb_path_exists` or `jsonb_path_match` on the where condition but was not able to make the query work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the query working as needed. Here is my proposal:

```
SELECT gallery 
FROM public.reviews, jsonb_path_query(data->'gallery', '$[*]') as gallery 
WHERE data->>'id' = '87b05c62-4153-4341-9b58-e86bade25ffd' and gallery->>'id' = 'aae64f19-22a8-4da7-b40a-fbbd8b2ef30b'
```

Hope it helps others.